# 1RX4 and 2RX4 RAM in HP Z820 Workstation

Tags: memory

HPZ820 workstation has 4 memory channels and presently 32GB (**4x8GB**) **1Rx4 PC3-14900R** RAM is installed in 4 black color sockets of each channel. Can I fill the white sockets by 32GB (**4x8GB**) **2Rx4 PC3-14900R** RAM? Or should I pair 1Rx4 with 1Rx4 and 2Rx4 with 2Rx4?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not, and HP recommends against it.

Each memory module in a channel should be identical to other modules in that same channel, and HP [explicitly states](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-z820-workstation/5225041/document/bph03886) mixing single rank (1Rx4) and dual rank (2Rx4) memory is not recommended:

> It is recommended to get the same type of memory (same size, same
>   speed, same manufacturer) for each slot. For best performance, get the
>   fastest memory that the motherboard supports.

FYI, the [workstation's spec sheet](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-z820-workstation/5225041/document/c03271150#AbT2) shows you have eight (8) channels of RAM on that [motherboard](https://www.itcreations.com/images/products/small/619562-001.jpg) ([reversed](https://www.itcreations.com/view_product.asp?product_id=31224#)), and only PC3-14900L LR DIMMs are supported for the 32GB size. LR modules use less power than standard DDR3 Registered modules, and (as per the [Memory Configuration document](http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/downloads/Z820_Memory_Configurations.pdf)):

> Unbuffered, Registered and LR DIMMs cannot be mixed in a system.

Comment: Interesting. I also called HP and opened a case for the same issue. To which following is their reply and it seems no problem when single and dual rank RAM are used in the system. 

"... After having the concerns checked at our end, we have not been able to find any issues with using a Single Channel RAM and a Dual Channel RAM in the unit. The only criteria being 1 type of Memory module should be installed in a single memory bank (The 2 slots in the logical order). Please check page 15 in the pdf attached for the slot order... "

Comment: Get a name and their location, so if they're underinformed, you're protected.

Comment: Then for example, if in one channel (pair of black and white slots) 1Rx4 PC3-14900R RAMs are installed. Can I then install 2Rx4 PC3-14900R RAMs on one of the other channels?

Comment: Unless there's something they're not telling us in the docs, yes.